# How to check if cookies value available on dynamically load page(infinite scroll)

Tags: javascript, cookies, infinite-scroll, document-ready

I need to change the font-size of content on click of a button and store them in a cookie, the code is working for page load on the first time but I have infinite scroll on the website and next page is not get the value from the cookie and font-size show in the default value.

I tried putting all code all inside (document)on('ready', function) or window.on(load)

```
 var Cookie = "fontsize";
$(document).ready(function () {    

    var fontsize = $.cookie(Cookie) || 'normal';

    if (fontsize == "normal") {
        $(".td-post-content p").css({
            "font-size": "20px"
        });
         console.log(fontsize + "normal state")
    }
    else  {          

       $( '.td-post-content p' ).css( 'font-size', $.cookie("fontsize") + "px");
       console.log(fontsize + "else state")
    };
}); 


function getSize() {
    if (Cookie){
        size =  $( '.td-post-content p' ).css( 'font-size', $.cookie("fontsize") + "px");
        size = parseInt(size, 10);
    }
        size = $('.td-post-content p').css( "font-size");
        size = parseInt(size, 10);
    } 

    getSize()
    console.log(size + "after getsize")

    $('#contentsWrapper').on( "click", "#up", function() {        
      if ((size + 1) <= 26) {
        $( ".td-post-content p" ).css( "font-size", "+=1" );
        $( "#font-size" ).text(  size += 1 );       
      }
       $.cookie(Cookie, fontsize = size, {expires: 365, path: '/', domain  : ''});
       console.log(size);
    });

    $('#contentsWrapper').on( "click", "#down", function() {
      if ((size - 1) >= 16) {
        $( ".td-post-content p" ).css( "font-size", "-=1" );
        $( "#font-size" ).text(  size -= 1  );
      }
       $.cookie(Cookie, fontsize = size, {expires: 365, path: '/', domain  : ''});
       console.log(size);
});
```

Comment: Suggest you modify a style tag instead of using inline style to account for elements that don't exist yet.

Comment: But how could I use cookie value into style tag?

Comment: By rewriting the text in the style tag

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an example of using a cookie value to update a style tag](https://jsfiddle.net/ywxkbsg7/10/).

Essentially, on page load you retrieve the cookie value and create a  tag to target your page content via CSS rules. That way it still applies to items which are loaded in later.

When you click the buttons, you need to update the cookie and then refresh the style tag.

**JS**

```
var cookie = "fontsize";

var getFontSize = function(){
    var value = parseInt($.cookie(cookie))
  return  value||20;
}

var changeFontSize = function(direction){
  var newSize = Math.min(25, Math.max(15, getFontSize()+direction))
  $.cookie(cookie, newSize, {expires: 365, path: '/', domain  : ''});
  updateFontSize(newSize)
}
var updateFontSize = function(fontsize){
  var style = $('#font_size_style')
  if(!style.length){
    style = $('<style id="font_size_style">')
    $(document.body).append(style)
  }
  style.text(".td-post-content p { font-size: "+fontsize+"px; }")
  $( "#font-size" ).text(fontsize);
}
var initFontSize = function(){
  var fontsize = getFontSize()
  console.log(fontsize)
  updateFontSize(fontsize)
}

$(document).ready(initFontSize); 

$('#contentsWrapper').on( "click", "#up", function() {        
  changeFontSize(1)
});

$('#contentsWrapper').on( "click", "#down", function() {
  changeFontSize(-1)
}); 

$("#add").on( "click",function() {
    var paragraphs = $(".td-post-content p")
  $(".td-post-content").append($("<p>Test paragraph "+(paragraphs.length+1)+"</p>"))
});
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<div id="contentsWrapper">
  <button id="up">^</button>
  <div id="font-size" style="display: inline-block; width: 30px;"></div>
  <button id="down">v</button>

  <div class="td-post-content">
    <p>
    Test paragraph 1
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
<button id="add">Add Paragraph
</button>
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer & cleaner code it's work perfectly for me

Comment: Just a small query, can u please explain how newSize calculation is working

var newSize = Math.min(24, Math.max(17, getFontSize()+direction))

Comment: It limits the value within a valid range. `Math.max(15, getFontSize()+direction)` ensures that the new size will not be less than 15, and `Math.min(25, ... )`ensures the new size will not be greater than 25.